# MongoDB - Can I create an index to isolate values in a document key for faster searching?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I am going to simplify this as much as I can because the database structure is a lot complex than this.

Let's assume that documents stored in my DB have the following structure:

```
[{
    
"items": [
      
"name1 , name2 , name3"
    ]
  },
  
{
    
"items": [
      
"name4 , name5 , name6 , name7"
    ]
}]
```

Now, to find a document where one of the values for the 'items' key is "name6", I am forced to use the regex like this:

```
db.collection.find({
  "items": {
    $regex: "name6",
    $options: "i"
  }
})
```

This is because the length of item values stored inside the 'items' key is variable and always stored as strings separated by a comma (e.g. "name4 , name5 , name6 , name7")

Anyways, such a search produces the desired outcome, like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "items": [
      "name4 , name5 , name6 , name7"
    ]
  }
]
```

However, while this works nicely on 10 thousand documents in my database, with 1 million documents it's already slow (+10 seconds) and the expected size of the database is over 1 billion documents; at which point this kind of approach is unusable.

I can't easily change how the JSON is structured, because that's coming from a third-party provider.
So, is there anything else I can do to speed up searching?

Can I create a serialized index to isolate values in this particular document key? Or in other words, can I index values stored in the 'items' key separately, like instructing indexing to create a separate index for each item? Any better approach?

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/X_MZ37h5Qvd

Comment: (Incidentally, there is no need to prefix your question titles with a tag/subject - that's what the tag system is for. We have a [relevant Meta discussion here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253028)).

Comment: I wonder if google and other indexing engines would completely agree with you.

Comment: They would. The `<title>` of each question page is automatically prefixed with the primary tag. On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65363507/detect-encoding-in-wrongly-encoded-utf-8-text-file), which is not manually tagged, the page title has `python - ` prefix.

Comment: Ok cool thanks. Now I wish the tagging system brought over someone to help me with the actual problem

Comment: Ha, yeah! I expect Stack Overflow are working on the AI for that `:=)`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/) on `items` field, I have not tested but I can say text search is better than `$regex` search and a normal index,

- Create text index:

```
db.collection.createIndex({ items: "text" });
```

- Your query would be:

```
db.collection.find({
    $text: { $search: "name6" }
})
```

> Read [text index restriction](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/text-search-operators/#query-framework) before you implement!