# Detect encoding in wrongly encoded UTF-8 text file

Tags: python, encoding

I have an encoding issue.

I have millions of text files that I need to parse for a language data science project. Each text file is encoded as UTF-8, but I just found that some of these source files are not encoded properly.

For example. I have a Chinese text file, that is encoded as UTF-8, but text in the file looks like this:

```
Subject: »Ø¸´: ÎÒÉý¼¶µ½
```

When I use Python to detect the encoding of this Chinese text file:

Chardet tells me the file is encoded as UTF-8:

```
with open(path,'rb') as f:
    data = ""
    data = f.read()
    encoding=chardet.detect(data)['encoding']
```

UnicodeDammit also tells me the file is encoded as UTF-8:

```
with open(path,'rb') as f:
    data = ""
    data = f.read()
    encoding= UnicodeDammit(data).original_encoding
```

Meanwhile, I know it's not UTF-8, it should be GB2312 Chinese encoding instead. If I open this file in Notepad++, it's detected also as UTF-8 and all Chinese characters show as gibberish. Only if I manually switch encoding in Notepad++ to GB2312 I get the proper text:

```
Subject: 禄脴赂麓: 脦脪脡媒录露碌陆
```

I have a number of files like this, in all kinds of languages.

Is there a way I can detect encoding in these badly encoded UTF-8 files?

Example text file can be downloaded here: https://gofile.io/d/qMcgkt

Comment: could you attach any files? maybe this could help someone helping you. For example you said some files are properly encoded whilst others are not. Accessing these files might help

Comment: @LeonardoMaffei, I added an example txt file to my original post.

Comment: With first 35 bytes from your file (==23 characters in UTF-8): `'Subject: »Ø¸´: ÎÒÉý¼¶µ½'.encode('latin1').decode('gb2312')` gives `'Subject: 回复: 我升级到'` and _Google Translate_ says it's `Subject: Re: I upgraded to` in English. Apparently, it's a flagrant _double_ [_mojibake_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case. The rest of your example file is total garbage.

Comment: No it's not garbage. When I use notepad++ it looks fine. Anyways, I think I have a solution now, just testing it on multiple text files.

Comment: I loaded the flie in notepad ++ and switched to GB2312.  Although it "looks fine" as Chinese, it is garbage text and doesn't translate correctly to anything.  @JosefZ is correct.  The subject is double mojibake.  `GB18030 is garbage also.  Just because it looks like Chinese characters doesn't mean it makes sense.  That codec just makes chinese characters out of the garbage.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, I've figured it out. Using CharsetNormalizerMatches seems to work, properly detecting the encoding. Anyways, this is how I implemented it and it works like a charm, correctly detecting gb18030 encoding for the file in question:

```
from charset_normalizer import CharsetNormalizerMatches as CnM
encoding = CnM.from_path(path).best().first().encoding
```

Note: The answer was hinted to me by someone who suggested using CharsetNormalizerMatches, but later deleted his post here. Too bad, I'd love to give him/her the credit.

Comment: For me, `encoding` returns `'ptcp154'` and  `data.decode(encoding)` gives _meaningful_ result `Subject: В»ГҳВёВҙ: ГҺГ’ГүГҪВјВ¶ВөВҪ` … `пҝҪпҝҪпҝҪпҝҪпҝҪпҝҪпҝҪпҝҪпҝҪж¶` (truncated)…

Comment: I guess the site gofile.io where I uploaded my example file must have done something to the text file. In any case, works fine for me. CharsetNormalizerMatches is the only solution that is working, just tried it on other files from other languages and it's working perfectly.
Please do not downvote, this is the solution that works.

Comment: @jjj Just wondering, can you read Chinese or have you run it through a translater?  the characters encoded in UTF8 in the sample text are mostly "REPLACEMENT CHARACTER".  UTF-8 can't accidently decode a file as it is a very specific encoding.  The file *is* UTF-8, the subject is mojibake that can be reversed to a real subject that translates roughly to "Re: My promotion" but the body characters are not reversable.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I think I am not getting correct results now. It seems that it's showing Chinese characters, but it's just some incorrect translation. This is turning out to be a real nightmare.

Comment: That's what I've been telling you.  You have double encoded mojibake.  The sample you shared was not recoverable except for the subject.

Comment: Yes, you were right, only the subject line was good, the rest if garbage. Do you think there is any chance whatsoever to make sense of that text?

Comment: Not for that sample.  The UTF-8 characters decode to U+FFFD (REPLACEMENT CHARACTER).  So the first incorrect decoding replaced characters it didn't understand and then that result was re-encoded as UTF-8.  It's was lossy so a one-way error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a definite encoding of your linked [example.txt](https://gofile.io/d/qMcgkt) file as concatenated two different encodings:

```
path = r'D:\Downloads\example.txt'
with open(path,'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

# double mojibake
print( data[:37].decode('utf-8').encode('latin1').decode('gb2312') )

# Chinese
print( data[37:].decode('gb2312') )
```

Result pasted into [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/?sl=auto&tl=en&op=translate) gives

> ```
> Subject: Re: I upgraded to
>
> The orange version of the orange version, should be corrected
> ```

*Unfortunately, SO thinks that Chinese text in the result is a spam so I can't embed it here…*

> Body cannot contain "".
>
> This appears to be spam. If you think we've made an error, make a post
> in meta.

**Edit**:  `print( data[:37].decode('gb18030'))` returns

```
Subject: 禄脴赂麓: 脦脪脡媒录露碌陆
```

[Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/?sl=auto&tl=en&op=translate) then gives **`Subject: Lulululu: Lululu Lulu`** as an English equivalent for the latter string.

Anyway, abovementioned `Subject: Re: I upgraded to` (or `Re: My promotion` [suggested by Mark Tolonen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65363507/detect-encoding-in-wrongly-encoded-utf-8-text-file/65365277?noredirect=1#comment115561211_65364949)) looks to be more meaningful than this…

Comment: The subject translates more to something like "Re: my promotion" but the other stuff is mostly the characters "锟斤拷" repeated, which is the unicode REPLACEMENT_CHARACTER encoded in UTF8 and decoded as GB2312.  It's nonsense.

Comment: `Subject: 回复: 我升级到

锟斤拷锟斤拷锟斤拷锟斤拷锟芥都锟斤拷锟斤拷锟斤拷锟斤拷锟斤拷锟斤拷锟桔版，应锟矫诧拷锟斤拷锟缴★拷` is mentioned fake spam… Sorry, I can't read Chinese…

Comment: Google [锟斤拷](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E9%94%9F%E6%96%A4%E6%8B%B7#:~:text=%E9%94%9F%E6%96%A4%E6%8B%B7%EF%BC%8C%E6%98%AF%E4%B8%80,%E4%B9%8B%E9%97%B4%E7%9A%84%E8%BD%AC%E6%8D%A2%E9%97%AE%E9%A2%98%E3%80%82)  It's a common sequence from mis-decoded Chinese.  The translation is: Kunjinkao is a string of garbled characters often seen on search engine pages and other websites. The garbled code stems from the conversion between GBK character set and Unicode character set

Comment: @MarkTolonen but _Google Translate_ gives me so-so sense (meaning)?

Comment: It's a poor attempt.  Trust me...I've studied Chinese and although I'm not very good at it, I know this is garbage.  The subject is double encoded and you got that right.  Subjects follow an RFC that can specify a different encoding than the body.  I suspect that's why it is right and the body is all replacement characters in UTF-8.